# Pulling an activity report from MS teams to show when users logged in and off

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-teams

im wondering if anyone can let me know how this can be done. we Use MS teams and i want to be able to get a report showing when users logged in and out (Became offline) is this possible with MS teams or do i need some reporting software.

any helps is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the Microsoft Graph API to get data out about teams. The [Teams API reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/microsoft-teams-user-activity-reports?view=graph-rest-1.0) v1 and beta versions, do cover user activity, but it is aggregated to a day level, and covers call counts, message numbers etc, it doesn't cover activity like logging in and out times.

Power BI can connect to and transform JSON Data out of this API, but it would be best to use an method, like an Azure Function, Azure DataBricks, Azure Data Factory to extract the data and store it in a more accessible location, like a database, blob storage or data lake.